# Flink: writing to dev/null

Tags: apache-flink

I want to execute my `Flink` `Scala` program without writing the result to a file. Running a program without saving the result `DataSet` into a `DataSink` isn't possible. So I tried `<result dataset name>.writeAsText("file:///dev/null", WriteMode.OVERWRITE)`. That didn't work. The following error occurred:

```
> java.io.IOException: Output path 'file:/dev/null' could not be
> initialized. Canceling task...    at
> org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileOutputFormat.open(FileOutputFormat.java:228)
>   at
> org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextOutputFormat.open(TextOutputFormat.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:187)
>   at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a way to use a DataSink with the dev/null path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `DiscardingOutputFormat`:

```
val data: DataSet[(String, Int)]
data.output(new DiscardingOutputFormat[(String, Int)]())
```